# Issue in playing fairplay video with avplayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, drm, fairplay

We have to play some encrypted videos from the server.
In `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` we got the `ckc` data correctly and responded with that. Then video just starts playing and stops immediately. When we checked the `playerItem` error description, we got:

`Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.}`.

Any one encountered this?